AttributeError: module 'torch.utils._pytree' has no attribute 'register_pytree_node'
I use pytorch 2.0.0 and transformer4.41.0.
I saw many people think it's transformers version problem, and use
pip install transformers==4.28.0 

to solve the problem, but it not work for me.
If it helps, I get this when:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/UrbanArchitect/main.py", line 17, in 
from utils.clip import CLIPScore
File "/Users/UrbanArchitect/utils/clip.py", line 2, in 
from transformers import CLIPProcessor, CLIPModel
File "/Users/anaconda3/envs/Newurban/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/init.py", line 26, in 
from . import dependency_versions_check
File "/Users/anaconda3/envs/Newurban/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/dependency_versions_check.py", line 16, in 
from .utils.versions import require_version, require_version_core
File "/Users/anaconda3/envs/Newurban/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/utils/init.py", line 33, in 
from .generic import (
File "/Users/anaconda3/envs/Newurban/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/utils/generic.py", line 474, in 
_torch_pytree.register_pytree_node(
AttributeError: module 'torch.utils._pytree' has no attribute 'register_pytree_node'


What code are you running to retrieve such an error?

It's an open source project on github.

When you show the code, I might be able to help you.

I was able to solve this by installing:
pip install torch==2.2


Worked for me too!
